# Limit the number of cores used

Tags: parallelization

Sometimes, when Mathematica thinks it is needed, it automatically threads a computation on several cores, it can happen for `NIntegrate` or `NDSolve` for example.

I am going to use a shared workstation, so I cannot risk that my program uses all the cores: is there a way to limit the use of cores in this case? Something similar to `LaunchKernels` used for *manual* parallelization.

**EDIT**
I have tried to change the default properties in the menu `Evaluation->Parallel Kernel Configurations`

The default was *When needed*, I have changed it to *Manual*, but Mathematica still tries to thread the computation over all the cores of the machine. Any idea?

If needed I am running version 12.3 for Linux

Comment: It would be nice if you provide an MWE so we could test our solutions.

Answer (score 1):

There are `SystemOptions["ParallelOptions"]`:

```
SystemOptions["ParallelOptions"]
```

> ```
> {"ParallelOptions" -> {"AbortPause" -> 2., "BusyWait" -> 0.01, "MathLinkTimeout" -> 15., 
>    "MKLThreadNumber" -> 4, "ParallelThreadNumber" -> 4, "RecoveryMode" -> "Retry", 
>    "RelaunchFailedKernels" -> True, 
>    "VectorParallelLengthThresholds" -> {8192, 8192, 8192, 8192, 8192}, 
>    "VectorVendorLengthThresholds" -> {128, 32, 32}}}
> ```

You can try changing the options:

```
SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> {"MKLThreadNumber" -> 1, "ParallelThreadNumber" -> 1}]
```

This works for the current Kernel session only.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you want to use only 2 kernels:

```
LaunchKernels[2]
```

To check how many kernels are in use currently, run

```
$KernelCount
```

Controlling physical cores instead of kernels/threads is an OS-side problem. You can check how many physical cores are available in the machine via `$ProcessorCount`, which is based on what OS is telling Mathematica.